# Showing the bootbox with the angular js data binded form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I started using Angular JS just 2 weeks back and is very much amazed with the data binding feature of it.

Also I am very fond of using [bootboxjs](http://bootboxjs.com) to show the messages and all the info to the user.

I am just thinking can we show the data binded form of Angular JS in bootbox through custom dialog.

I tried but I am not getting the content infact the dialog box is showing the the template as it is and not with the data.

How  can we show the data in bootbox UI with the data already binded with it.

Answer (score 10):

You must use the $compile.

http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/guide/compiler

As example:

```
            var tplCrop = '<div><img ng-src="{{file.src}}"/></div>';
            var template = angular.element(tplCrop);
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var html= linkFn($scope);

            bootbox.dialog({
                message: html,
                title: "My title",
                buttons: {
                    ok: {
                        label: "Ok",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {
                        }
                    },
                    close: {
                        label: "Close",
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function () {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: its really helpful .. works good for me.. another example on http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this pretty good example <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5BtB8i?p=preview)**</kbd> how to pass data to Dialog.

However its not bootbox (that uses jQuery). The demo shows dialog based only on bootstrap and angualrJS.

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand this can be done, but we have to write that much code to do that infact, in case of bootbox we can just do the things in single line of code...
so I am looking for something more towards bootbox and angular js
anyways +1 for showing this as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a very nice module, to handle that with separate template file!
https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngbootbox

very nice!

Comment: This answer ended up in the low quality review queue, but the project does indeed appear to solve the OP's problem -- therefore I'm voting to leave it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old question, but in addition to the top-rated answer, which I am unable to comment on currently, one needs to consider the life-cycle of the dialog box.

```
let tplCrop = '<div><img ng-src="{{file.src}}"/></div>';
let template = angular.element(tplCrop);
ley linkFn = $compile(template);
let childScope = $scope.$new();
let html= linkFn(childScope);

bootbox.dialog({
    message: html,
    title: "My title",
    buttons: {
        ok: {
            label: "Ok",
            className: "btn-success",
            callback: function () {
            }
        },
        close: {
            label: "Close",
            className: "btn-danger",
            callback: function () {
            }
        },
        onHide: function(e){
            childScope.$destroy();
        }
    }
});
```

I discovered the issue with AngularJS v1.8.2 and the select directive; when the options were statically define it was observed that the value in the model would be set to null shortly after the the dialog was dismissed. The behaviour was corrected by using the `childScope` as above.

If the options are static e.g. `<option value="abc">abc</option>` when the dialog box is dismissed, the options are removed from the DOM. The AngularJS code is informed of the removal and eventually sets the value in the model to null.

This does not appear to happen when the options are generated using the ng-options attribute, presumable because angular is in charge of disposal of the options.

By destroying the `childScope` just before the dialog is removed from the DOM, the removal of the options from the DOM does not affect the value in the `$scope`.

Hopefully this will help other people maintaining legacy code.